# middleware auth with except method dont work for a parameter

Tags: laravel

My problem is that :

```
$this->middleware('auth', ['except'=>'getInfos', 'store']);
```

My getInfos except is working, but the store method dont work, i cant understand why, you can see in the picture below my rout list (in the terminal).

[picture of my code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLEiD.png)

I searched everywhere for nothing, do you see a difference between store and GetInfos ?

Thanks in advance all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be as a multidimensional array:

```
$this->middleware('auth', ['except'=> ['getInfos', 'store']]);
```

Or with better view:

```
$this->middleware('auth')->except('getInfos', 'store');
```

Comment: this kind of moments where you would prefer not to have asked the question lol thanks a lot Martin, it's strange i was using this code in a previous project without any problem x_o